# link is not working

Tags: php

The top link in my list of posts in this WordPress site is not working (http://hautedishwi.com/category/recipes/).  After Cherry Doughnuts there is some text that says "Get the recipe" but it is not a link.  The others all work. The code, via Firebug, shows this:

```
<br&hellip; class="read_more" href="http://hautedishwi.com/2011/06/03/cherry-doughnuts/" <a="">Get the recipe</br&hellip;>
```

I also think the code in functions.php that is screwing it up is:

```
function twentyten_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '&hellip;' . twentyten_continue_reading_link();
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

but I'm not sure as I'm not a programmer.  Any idea how to get this link working?  Appreciate your help, as always!

Comment: You forgot a greater-than sign so you end up with `<br&hellip;` instead of `<br />`.

Comment: @Borealid has the answer.  Check your recipe text and make sure you closed out your `<br />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
&gt; &hellip;
```

rather than

```
&hellip;
```

Because it's missing the ">" of the line break.